# SQLite Select Query Multiple Where Clause Values

Tags: sqlite

I have a statement like so...

`SELECT * FROM FOO_TABLE WHERE ID = 1;`

What I want is to be able to supply multiple ID's without having to `AND`. So for example....

`SELECT * FROM FOO_TABLE WHERE ID = 1,2,3,4` or `(1,2,3,4)`.

Something along those lines. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link:

[sqlite](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg03941.html)

`SELECT id, . FROM additionalchunks WHERE id in (? ? ? ? ? .)`

works, and works efficiently (with an index) :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm getting a syntax error from this when I try and insert values instead of the ? placeholder?

Comment: Hmm, try something like `SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE AGE IN ( 25, 27 );` , from [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_where_clause.htm]

Comment: Nice work. Thank you for taking the time to help me. Couldn't find it myself.